# Using AJAX to Read an XML (or JSON) feed, how can I pass the Data to my code behind so I can work with it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I work somewhere where the webserver (intranet) does not have internet access.  I have to access data from another department by either XML or JSON feed.

I am currently able to do this using JavaScript because the clients DO have internet access.  Its a hack and I'm not happy with it because I'm terrible with JavaScript and would rather work in code behind.

The below code currently works but I would rather that the page loads, Ajax grabs the XML and I send the data to the code behind and I can then feed a Repeater or manipulate the code.  Any insight would be helpful.

Thank you.

Current Ajax

```
<div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none'>
   <img src='/js/newsdesk/loader.gif' class="ajax-loader" />
</div>

<ul id="army"></ul>
<script src="/js/newsdesk/dynamic-newsdesk.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        displayContent('/js/newsdesk/army.xml', 'army');
    } );
```

My .js file

```
function displayContent(url, tag) {
$('#loadingmessage').show();  // show the loading message.
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: {
        key: "value"
    },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {

        var totalCount = $(xml).find('totalCount').first().text();
        var $article = $(xml).find("article");

        if (totalCount > 0) {
            $article.each(function () {

                var title = $(this).find('title').text();

                var url = $(this).find('articleUrl').text();
                var datetime = $(this).find('publicationDate').text();
                var publicationName = $(this).find('publication > name').text();

                $("#" + tag).append('<li><a href=' + url + ' target=_blank>' + title + '</a><br/><p style=\"font-size: smaller;\"> <em>(' + publicationName + ') ' + datetime + '</em></p></li>');
            });
        }

        else {
            $("#" + tag).append('No articles.');
        }
        $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide the loading message
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way for this would be to use an ASP.NET WebMethod.  A WebMethod is a part of ASP.NET that will let you do an AJAX call to a page.  There are different approaches for whether you want the method to have access to session data (or not), so be aware of that.  There's some neat demo code here:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

### Addendum

If you have to interact with the page controls, then you could:

- In Javascript, serialize your data to a string
- In Javascript, stuff that data into an element corresponding to a HiddenField
- In Javascript, trigger a postback
- In your code-behind, deserialize your data from the HiddenField, modify your Repeater, and let ASP.NET return the results as normal

  This is a pain in the butt, but it will work.

Comment: I had actually looked at that example but I wasn't clear how I would get the data, which is returned to the page, into a repeater from the code behind?

Comment: See addendum above.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to do a ClientSide request from the code behind, ie down kind of httprequest?

Comment: No, because your Javascript code is grabbing XML to push toward the back end, and not the other way 'round.